# validate html syntax using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

how do I validate a string of html using javascript/jquery
e.g of html string

```
   <style type="text/css">     
     .nai {position:absolute;top:0px;right:0px;z-index:90000;
      background-image:url("http://example.com/test.png");
      background-repeat:no-repeat;width:19px;height:15px;}

     .nai:hover {width: 77px;
      background-image:url("http://example.com /test.png");}
    </style>
   <div style="width:160px;height:600px;position:absolute"></div>
```

am looking for basic validations like.whether start/end tag is proper or not

tried using jquery's fns as follows

```
  var $str1 = $(str1); // html string into real html 

  var len = $str1.length;
    // console.log($str1);
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
      if(typeof $($str1[i]).get(0).outerHTML!='undefined'){
        final1+=unescapeHtml($($str1[i]).get(0).outerHTML);
      }

   }
```

but above code doesnt validate & rectify child elments tag/or start tag of an element if absent.

Comment: why do you need it? Isn't your browser doing it for you?

Comment: @Jai without having a proper use case in mind. i wouldnt post here

Comment: what use case? if any closing tag is missing, browsers add the closing of that tag right after it. then how any js would try to check if a closing tag is missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box solution for validating (or parsing) HTML with JavaScript, and you can't just abuse DOM for that purpose.
You would have find some 3rd party library (like the one from **Dagriel**'s answer) or write a parser/validator yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate that a string contains valid html syntax by using the DOMParser()

Example here: https://tonylea.com/checking-for-valid-html-strings-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at:

https://github.com/peterjwest/html_validator

The aim of this project is this:

- To allow anyone on any browser be able to validate HTML, either using a bookmarklet or browser extension
- To support the major doctypes: HTML 4.01, XHTML 1.0 and eventually HTML 5
- To provide a plain English, sensible version of the W3C HTML spec

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I agree, that's why I added the goals of the project. I will have your suggestion in mind, thanks!